# How to page through individual records in MVC3. Access Style

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic

I'm in the process of recreating our website using MVC3.  I can not wrap my head around a solution to reproduce some old site functionality.

Our current site displays a parcel and displays two buttons, nextID, previousID each of those buttons returns a url string from a call to a function (ASP Classic) that looks like this.

```
Function GetNextID()

    Dim Temp

    SQLStmt.CommandText = "SELECT AccountNumber FROM " & DBOwner & "DataProperty Where cardnumber=1 and NBC <> 'TPMH' and LUC <> '6832' and closed = 0 and ParcelID > '" & PropertyID & "' order by ParcelID asc"

    RSProp.Open SQLStmt

    If Not RSProp.EOF Then
        Temp = RSProp("AccountNumber")
    Else
        Temp = ""
    End If

    RSProp.Close    

    GetNextID = Temp

End Function 'GetNextID
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a way to page data at the detail level inherently designed in MVC3?

What I don't want to do is this...

```
ViewResult Show(string parcelId)
{
  if(Request["next"] == "next")
    return _service.GetNextId(parcelId);
  if(Request["prev"] == "prev")
   return _service.GetPrevId(parcelId);
   //Or return this parcel
   return _service.getProperty(parcelId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to do this in the viewModel I've decided.

I'll just have a property on the ViewModel, .PriorId and .NextId

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it the following way:

```
ViewResult Next(int parcelId)
{
    return View("Show",_service.GetNextId(parcelId));
}

ViewResult Prev(int parcelId)
{
   return View("Show", _service.GetPrevId(parcelId));
}

ViewResult Show(int parcelid)
{
   var model = new Parcel();// replace Parcel with your model class here 

   // Here get all the Parcel properties from DB or from whereever.
   ...
   return View(model);
}
```

P.S. Can you also show your ASP Classic markup? Maybe I'll be able to suggest something better